# Is there an oveview of organizations support of segwit/segwit2X?

Tags: blockchain-fork, segregated-witness, segwit2x

I'm trying to get an overview of what parts of the ecosystem that support what, preferably by economic activity. Is there any good lists or overviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Segwit and Segwit2x are two different things. Segwit has already activated, Segwit2x has not. Please do not conflate the two.

https://coin.dance/poli and http://segwit.party/nya/ list the positions of various companies and project's on Segwit2x although they are not always accurate or clear.

Comment: There's also http://nob2x.org which gives an overview of companies that have not signed the NYA.